# Does pinning a webpage to homescreen clear cookies?

Tags: javascript, sveltekit, pocketbase

I have a sveltekit webapp using pocketbase that stores the authentication in cookies. If I use the browser on android normally, opening page and going to the vercel deployed page the authentication cookie works normally. If i close browser, clear tabs and everything if i come back it still automatically logs in. So far so good.

However when I pin my application with "add to desktop" the cookies disappear and I need to login again every time I open the application through the desktop shortcut ?

What am I missing? How can I better debug this issue?